# How to get name of variable in R (substitute)?

Tags: r, variables, substitution

I stacked with trying to pass variable through few functions, and on the final function I want to get the name of the original variable. But it seems like substitute function in R looked only in "local" environment, or just for one level up. Well, let me explain it by code:

```
fun1 <- function (some_variable) {deparse(substitute(some_variable)}
fun2 <- function (var_pass) { fun1 (var_pass) }
my_var <- c(1,2) # I want to get 'my_var' in the end
fun2 (my_var) # > "var_pass"
```

Well, it seems like we printing the name of variable that only pass to the fun1. Documentation of the substitute tells us, that we can use env argument, to specify where we can look. But by passing *.Global* or *.BaseNamespaceEnv* as an argument to substitute I got even more strange results - "some_variable"

I believe that answer is in this function with using env argument, so, could you please explain me how it works and how can I get what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure "The R-Inferno" touches on this. BTW, I'm assuming you meant to call `fun1` inside `fun2` with `var_pass` ?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Yes, I meant fun1(var_pass).

Comment: Why do you need the name in the first place.  There is probably a good, simpler alternative.

Comment: Well, I do a lot of computation for the data.frame, but in the end I would like to get access to the list (my_list$my_var), to get some data, that related to the data.frame. Probably there is some way to do it, I actually done what I need, but it was really messy. I put the name of variable as additional column, but with big datasets it is really slow down the process

Comment: If you need data inside a function,  simply pass it on as an input argument.  Similarly,  if you need anything from within the function outside the function,  use the return argument. Does this suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but not really. But I will think about this way. Thanks anyway! ))

Comment: If you want better feedback, I would recommend you add more information as to what you are trying to accomplish,  and why my suggestion does not work.

Comment: You might find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html helpful - it explains the problem and how you should design your functions to avoid it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest you consider passing optional name value to these functions. I say this because it seems like you really want to use the name as a label for something in the end result; so it's not really the variable itself that matters so much as its name. You could do

```
fun1 <- function (some_variable, name=deparse(substitute(some_variable))) {
    name
}
fun2 <- function (var_pass, name=deparse(substitute(var_pass))) { 
    fun1 (var_pass, name) 
}
my_var <- c(1,2)

fun2(my_var)
# [1] "my_var"

fun1(my_var)
# [1] "my_var"
```

This way if you end up having some odd variable name and what to give a better name to a result, you at least have the option. And by default it should do what you want without having to require the name parameter.

Comment: This one is interesting! )) But the problem I think in the R itself. I would even in the init() step add name parameter, but as I've already said, it is not the comfortable way with data.frames

Comment: I don't undetstand your comment @EvilAnton. I'm not sure what the `init()` step is or how this specifically relates to data.frames. If you want to use `name` to extract a column from a data.frame, you can use `df[, name]` if the value in `name `exactly matches one of the column names.

Comment: Init step I meant. When you load all data to the workspace. But actually, you made a good point. If to rename some of the column names that it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach I'd like to suggest is to use `rlang::enexpr`.
The main advantage is that we don't need to carry the original variable name in a parameter. The downside is that we have to deal with expressions which are slightly trickier to use.

```
> fun1 <- function (some_variable) {
    message("Entering fun1")
    rlang::enexpr(some_variable)
}
> fun2 <- function (var_pass) {
    message("Entering fun2")
    eval(parse(text=paste0("fun1(", rlang::enexpr(var_pass), ")")))
}
> my_var <- c(1, 2)
> fun1(my_var)
#Entering fun1
my_var
> fun2(my_var)
#Entering fun2
#Entering fun1
my_var
```

The trick here is that we have to evaluate the argument name in `fun2` and build the call to `fun1` as a `character`. If we were to simply call `fun1` with `enexpr(var_pass)`, we would loose the notion of `fun2`'s variable name, because `enexpr(var_pass)` would never be evaluated in `fun2`:

```
> bad_fun2 <- function (var_pass) {
    message("Entering bad fun2")
    fun1(rlang::enexpr(var_pass))
}
> bad_fun2(my_var)
#Entering bad fun2
#Entering fun1
rlang::enexpr(var_pass)
```

On top of that, note that neither `fun1` nor `fun2` return variable names as character vectors. The returned object is of class `name` (and can of course be coerced to `character`).
The bright side is that you can use `eval` directly on it.

```
> ret <- fun2(my_var)
#Entering fun2
#Entering fun1
> as.character(ret)
[1] "my_var"
> class(ret)
[1] "name"
> eval(ret)
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One hack, probably not the best way:

```
fun2 <- function (var_pass) { fun1 (deparse(substitute(var_pass))) }

fun1 <- function (some_variable) {(some_variable))}

fun2(my_var)
# "my_var"
```

And you could run `get` on that.  But as Paul H, suggests, there are better ways to track variables.

Comment: If somebody can lead me where to look to find the better way I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Well, one way I see to make what I need happened, is to pass char all the time through functions and just use get(). But it is not looked good for me, at least from the way of programming architecture.