# Why do I have to loose colnames if I select only one dataframe's column?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to select a column on a dataframe but I need to keep its column name. Imagine it as a one column dataframe. For example, this is what I need to accomplish:

```
df <- data.frame(col_a = c(1,2,3), col_b = c(5,2,8))
x <- df$col_a
colnames(x)
col_a # THIS VALUE IS WHAT I NEED
```

If you ask `R` for a `colname` of a vector, it simply returns `NULL`. Makes sense, but what if it was a column of a dataframe instead of a simple vector?

**Why do I need this?** I'm writing a function with `ggplot2` and I need to specify in a `lab` which column is it using to plot the results. I would rather NOT use a string text on my function to select the columns with the function if possible because it is much easier to select variables from a dataframe when iterating.

So basically `function(target, values) {...` where the arguments are both these kind of "vectors/one-column-dataframes" and the input would be like `my_function(target = df$col_a, values = df$col_b)` so I could get the `colnames(target)` and `colnames(values)`. Yes?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subassignment for more information on simplifying vs. preserving.

Comment: `df["col_a"]` (no commas) works as well.

Comment: I think you are missing the important part of the question here which is the function where you want to use this value and what exactly you are passing to it. A function can get the name of the variable passed to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309910/how-to-get-name-of-variable-in-r-substitute  but a variable can't keep track of it's own name (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.frame is a list and columns are its elements. If you extract a column and want to keep its name too you can not use `$`, if you have to get the column name as well along with column values use `[`

```
 df
 #   col_a col_b
 # 1     1     5
 # 2     2     2
 # 3     3     8
```

If extracting by giving column name (`$`), only values would come, if extracting by column position (`[`), it gives column name + values in that column. This `[` can hold element positions by number or name, but preserves name

**$**

```
 df$col_a
 # [1] 1 2 3
```

**[**

```
 df[1]
 #   col_a
 # 1     1
 # 2     2
 # 3     3
```

---

---

Behaviour of List (As we said above data.frame is a list)

```
 my_list <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:3, c= 4)
```

To extract values *in element* **a**

**Element Name** - Gives Only values

```
 my_list$a
 # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

To extract values *of element* in position **1**

**Element Position** - Gives Element Name + Values in the Element

```
 my_list[1]
 # $a
 # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

More help, in R console, type

```
 ?`[`
```

Answer (score 2):

a data frame originally is a list so you can subset using `$`. However, to preserve the dataframe characteristics when creating a new column (list) you need to use `drop=F`

```
x<- df[,"col_a",drop=F]
colnames(x)
[1] "col_a"
```

Comment: Yep, I get it @a-suliman but the idea is to NOT write all that "code" to simply get the vectors into the function. Know what I mean? Thanks for the super fast reply