# Extracting the user-written command line for a function

Tags: function, command, user-input

I am creating the following function:

```
mymean <- function(x){
  xmean <- mean(x)
  xmean <- as.data.frame(xmean)
  xmean
     }
```

When I use this function in the example below:

```
mymean(mtcars$mpg)
```

I get this result:

```
    xmean
1 20.09062
```

How can I get the name of the actual variable (i.e. **mpg**) input by the user in the result above instead of **xmean**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mymean <- function (x, xname=deparse(substitute(x))) {
  xmean <- mean(x)
  names(xmean) <- xname
  xmean
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310574/972791)