# R get object name when is input of another function

Tags: r, variables, substitution

I'd like to get the name of an object that is inputed into a function with another name.
Given

```
new_object = 10
fun1 <- function(fun_input){
  ...
}

fun1(fun_input = new_object)
```

The desired output of `fun1` should be the string `"new_object"`.

I tried `deparse` and `substitute` as suggested in the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309910/how-to-get-name-of-variable-in-r-substitute) but I only get `"fun_input"` as output.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share your code? I have no problem getting the output.

```
new_object = 10
new_object
[1] 10

fun1 <- function(fun_input) {
   deparse(substitute(fun_input))
}

fun1(new_object)
[1] "new_object"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

I suspect that in your function you are doing (evaluating) `fun_input` with further steps (for example a loop etc...) The thing is that from the time you first use `fun_input` it is an evaluated expression (quasi the result). To avoid this we have to capture `fun_input` with `substitute`.

Now you get an object `new_object` that can be treated as a list:

```
fun1 <- function(fun_input) {
  substitute(fun_input)
}

fun1(new_object)
new_object

new_object[[1]]
[1] 10
```

Comment: Surely the last expression `new_object[[1]]` is just evaluating the global variable `new_object`, it has nothing to do with `fun1`.  It wouldn't work if `new_object` was in some other environment.

Comment: but then the output would be a "symbol" but not string, which could be a problem if you direct the output to some other function (e.g. `data.frame()` do not accept "symbol")