# Use input of a function as variable name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, rename

I have a simple function in R to modify a dataframe

```
monthly_fun <- function(x){
x  %>% 
  mutate(obstime = convert_dates(obstime)) %>% 
  select(obstime, x = obsvalue)
}
```

When applying the function to dataframe `df`, i.e. `monthly_fun(df)`, I would like `df` to be the name of `obsvalue`. In my current code, the name is obviously `"x"`, how can I modify the part in `select` to get the name of the supplied dataframe as the variable name instead?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**: I want to apply this function to several dataframes using

```
result <- list( df1, df2, df3) %>%
    lapply( monthly_fun )
```

Comment: You may use `deparse(substitute(x))`.
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24309910/8806649)

Comment: Or  `ensym(x)` instead of `x` in `select(obstime, x = obsvalue)`

Comment: My solution does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the name of input by `deparse(substitute(x))`, and use `!!y := obsvalue` in `mutate()`.

```r
monthly_fun <- function(x) {
  y <- deparse(substitute(x))
  x  %>% 
    mutate(obstime = convert_dates(obstime),
           !!y := obsvalue) %>% 
    select(obstime, y)
}
```

A simplified example:

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  y <- deparse(substitute(x))
  x  %>% 
    mutate(!!y := 1) %>% 
    select(y)
}

fun(df)

#       df
#  1     1
#  2     1
#  3     1
#  4     1
#  5     1
```

---

###### Update

If you want to apply it to several data frames stored in a list, you should design a 2-argument function, one argument for data and the other for new column names. Then use `Map()` to apply this function over each pair of data and names.

```r
fun <- function(x, y) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(!!y := 1) %>% 
    select(y)
}

Map(fun, list(df1, df2), c("name1", "name2"))

# [[1]]
#     name1
# 1       1
# 2       1
# 3       1
# 4       1
# 5       1
#
# [[2]]
#     name2
# 1       1
# 2       1
# 3       1
# 4       1
# 5       1
```

If you're familiar with `purrr`, The use of `Map` can be replaced with `map2()` or `imap()`. (Notice the difference of inputs to the both functions)

```r
library(purrr)

# (1) map2(): Input data and names separately
map2(list(df1, df2), c("name1", "name2"), fun)

# (2) imap(): Input a named list
imap(list(name1 = df1, name2 = df2), fun)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does work, but when I try to apply it to several dataframes, for instance if I create 2 dataframes iris1 and iris2:
list( iris1, iris2) %>%
lapply( monthly_fun )
it does not work anymore. Thanks again !

Comment: @user6441253 See my update! Does it help? You can adjust the names as whatever you want. E.g. if you want the column names to be the same as the data names, just use `Map(fun, list(df1, df2), c("df1", "df2"))`. The name vector `c("df1", "df2")` can be automatically created by `paste()` or `ls(pattern = "input regex pattern here")`

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot and sorry for the delay !

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion by Julien and creating a variable using `deparse(substitute(df))` and rename using that.

```
monthly_fun <- function(x) {
  y = deparse(substitute(x))
     x <- x %>% 
         mutate(obstime = obstime*5) %>%
         select(obstime, obsvalue)
     names(x)[names(x) == "obsvalue"] <- y
     return(x)
}
```

see [this site](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/rename-the-column-name-in-r-using-dplyr/#:%7E:text=Rename%20the%20column%20name%20in%20R%20can%20be,%28%29%2C%20which%20can%20be%20used%20for%20different%20criteria.) for more naming methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But I was imprecise in my question, see my comment to Darren Tsai's answer. I edited the question, thanks again !